# using offset rows in T-SQL change sort order

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by

I recently discovered that when using "offset x rows" with the "fetch next x rows only" and "order by" command, items with the same value may appear in a different order.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Rows ORDER BY [IntegerField] OFFSET 0 ROWS

Output:
ID  IntegerField
1   1
2   1
3   2
```

But by adding fetch next 50 rows only

```
SELECT * FROM Rows ORDER BY [IntegerField] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY

Output:
ID  IntegerField
2   1
1   1
3   2
```

In real life I'm using a GUID data type as an identifier, so maybe that is the reason for this weird behavior?

Comment: may be not related, but is `3 2` line a typo error in your first example or is there an insert between the two examples ?

Comment: Unless the column(s) and/or expression(s) you identify in your `ORDER BY` clause produce unique value(s) for all rows, then all rows which have the same value(s) may be returned in any order that the server finds convenient. If you *need* a *specific* ordering, the only way to guarantee it is to spell out that ordering requirement in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @tschmit007 thanks! It was a typo from my side. I have edited the post.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know it's been a while, but you should post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but found this on MSDN :

> The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.

[ORDER BY Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

It is not specified that because the result contains twice (or more) the same value the order is not guaranteed but I guess this is implicit.